# Conditional Required Field in SharePoint Online Library Validation Syntax Error

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, modern-experience, validation, list-validation

### Goal

I have a "Managed Services" `Choice` column with predefined choices displaying as `Checkboxes (allow multiple selections)`.
I want to make another column required based on the selection of the "Managed Services" dropdown.

I used Library Validation on a SharePoint Online List with the new experience enabled.

### Problem

I can not Save my Validation Settings: `The formula contains a syntax error or is not supported.`

[image: Error]

### My Columns

#### Overview

[image: Overview of my columns]

#### Managed Services

[image: Managed Services column]

### Examples

`If` "Managed Services" `equals` "Managed Service für Client" `set` "Produkt Client" `required`

`If` "Managed Services" `equals` "Managed Service für Server" `set` "Produkt Server" `required`

### What I have tried so far

```
=IF([Managed Services]="Managed Service für Client",IF(ISBLANK([Produkt Client]),FALSE,TRUE),TRUE)
```

[image: What I have tried so far]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue with SharePoint formulas.

Multi-selection fields (Choice or Person/group or lookup) are not supported in SharePoint formulas.

If you are using SharePoint online modern experience, you have to customize the list form using Power Apps to apply validation for list form fields.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try to solve it using a Power App.